# Angular ui router multiple views with route(state) parameters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, multiple-views

I have a page where I show 2 different lists of products using multiple views with each having a controller and template file. My state definition is like this:

```
    .state('all_lists', {
      url: '/lists',
      views: {
      '' : {templateUrl: 'my-lists.html'},
      'featured@all_lists' : {templateUrl: 'featured.html', controller: 'featuredCtrl'},
      'deals@all_lists' : {templateUrl: 'deals.html', controller: 'dealsCtrl'}
      }
     }
    )
```

Each individual list has pagination and sorting filters at the top and these pagination and sorting filters are added to the URL as state parameters. 
Please tell me how to define these parameters for views of a state so that they can be added to URL and then used in the respective controllers.

If you have any better idea of displaying such a list of products with pagination parameters added to URL, please share your ideas.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

**NOTE:**
Please note that, I need to display both the lists on 1 page. Its kind of a homepage and featured Items list and then below that hot deals Items list is displayed and both of these lists have pagination, sorting and few other filters.
URL will be something like this.
mydomain.com/products/featured-page_1/deals-page_2/perpage_10/

**NOTE 2:**
After researching a lot and investigating, I have found out that this a clear case of **Parallel States**. Please tell me how to implement parallel states using the URL parameters scheme I am using currently.

```html
<html>
  <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <h1>Products Homepage</h1>
      <h3>Some common filters for both lists</h3>
    <div id="featured">
      <h2>Featured List</h2>
      <div>pagination and other filters</div>
      <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
        <li>item 4</li>
        <li>item 5</li>
      </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="deals">
        <h2>Hot Deals List</h2>
      <div>pagination and other filters for hot deals</div>
      <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
        <li>item 4</li>
        <li>item 5</li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Do you need the parameters to allow users to bookmark or is it because you expect people to write manually those urls?

Comment: I need the parameters in the URL to make the application persist its state without using local or session storage and user can also bookmark any state of the application. Please note that besides pagination and sorting there are also some advanced filters as well which are added to URL as parameters.

Comment: you are writing like a **thumbnail view** and **list view**.
can you show a sample url? you want only pagination? or if u accept any other alternative **I can suggest you**. let me know your complete requirement because I have implemented this for my application.

Comment: @AbdulHaseeb are you therE?

Answer (score 6):

Instead of having it as multiple views, Have them as child views with parent being abstract. Look at the code below,

```
$stateProvider
    .state("product", {
        url: '/product',
        templateUrl: "/Views/productHome.html",
        abstract: true,
        controller: "productHomeCtrl"
    })
    .state('product.thumbnailview', {
        url: '/producttv',
        templateUrl: "/Views/thumbnailview.html",
        controller: "thumbnailViewCtrl",
        params: {
            param1: null,
            param2: null
        }
    })
    .state('product.listview', {
        url: '/productlv',
        templateUrl: "Views/listview",
        controller: "listViewCtrl",
        params: {
            param1: null,
            param2: null
        }
    })
```

Now you can use the params by injecting **stateParams** service separately in your respective controllers.
**Note:**
         Also your product State **can never have** stateParams at all.

**Note**: But if you try to reach to product state directly it will not get activated because it is **abstract** state 
    How ever you can handle pagination by having the markup in either productHome.html globally or the respective views.

If your keeping the pagination in productHome.html you can still access the productDetails array using **$scope.$parent.productList** and reuse the same scope variable.

So in this case you will your productHome.html will like this

```
<div> 
    <div > MENU OPTIONS </div>
    <div ng-view>   </div>
    <ul uib-pagination total-items="itemLength" ng-model="currentPage" ng-change="pageChanged()"></ul>
</div>
```

These three objects can be handled in any of the three controllers

1. itemLength
2. currentPage
3. pageChanged()

Both thumbnails and list view will contain markups for the layout purpose only.

```
<div>
    <div> Thumbnail or List markup </div> very simple you can play with bootstrap grid layout.
</div
```

### Update 1

For a route like this

```
//mydomain.com/products/featured-page_1/deals-age_2/perpage‌​_10/
```

Using my solution you can handle it something like this

```
//mydomain.com/products/featured/page_1/deals/age_2/
```

So your child states will be

```
$stateProvider
    .state("product", {
        url: '/product',
        templateUrl: "/Views/productHome.html",
        abstract: true,
        controller: "productHomeCtrl"
    })
    .state('product.featured/', {
        url: '/featured/:number',
        templateUrl: "/Views/featured.html",
        controller: "featuredCtrl",
        params: {
            number: null,
        }
    })
    .state('product.deals', {
        url: '/deals/:number',
        templateUrl: "Views/deals.html",
        controller: "dealsCtrl",
        params: {
            number: null
        }
})
```

In the **featuredCtrl** you can access those parameters using

```
$stateParam.number
```

In the **dealsCtrl** you can access those parameters using

```
$stateParam.number
```

Have the **perpage** value in the **$rootscope** or in the **productHomeCtrl**

Comment: Thank you so much for an elaborated answer. Please note that I have to display both the lists on 1 page. If I use multiple states then how can I display them on 1 page. Please check edited question summary.

Comment: what are the parameters you want to have in routing??

Comment: URL with parameters will be something like this:
//mydomain.com/products/featured-page_1/deals-page_2/perpage_10/

Comment: which of these are the parameters ?? and which parameter you want in which controller?

Comment: after /products/ all the URL segments are parameters and I am differentiating the parameters by adding 'viewname-' like, 'featured-' and 'deals-' prefix to the parameters names so that I can get the paramters in individual controllers

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time, I have understood how the parameters will work however this question of mine is still not answered yet. 
Please note that I have to display both the lists on 1 page. If I use multiple states then how can I display them on 1 page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128131/discussion-between-aravind-and-abdul-haseeb).

Answer (score 2):

You just need to specify the params on the url and call them in the controller

```
.state('all_lists', {
  url: '/lists?dealPage&featPage&otherParam',
  views: {
  '' : {templateUrl: 'my-lists.html'},
  'featured@all_lists' : {templateUrl: 'featured.html', controller: 'featuredCtrl'},
  'deals@all_lists' : {templateUrl: 'deals.html', controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
     $scope.page= $stateParams.dealPage;
     $scope.otherParam= $stateParams.otherParam;
  }}
  }
 }
)
```

Comment: How would I know that 'page' parameter belongs to which view? because $stateParams.page will be used in both the view controllers.

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to add a page parameter for every view in order to store every list pagination state  in the URL, it feels a little bit tricky but they do it that others web frameworks like JSF, ASPMVC.